# Compiler saying indexOf function isnt a function

Tags: javascript, html

So basically, i am making a makeshift form that gets user input and i want to check the email field for the "@" and "." symbols. However whenever I run it, it says that indexOf is not a function. Wondered what I was doing wrong.`

```
function checker(){
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var name = document.getElementById('Name');
  var d = emails.indexOf("@");
  var x = emails.indexOf(".");
  if (d == -1)
    alert("Invalid email address given!!");
  else if (x == -1)
    alert("Invalid email address given!!");
}
```

Comment: Sure? Your dev tools are right, and that error is 100% correct and you should have looked a little closer at your own code: `emails` is not a string, it's an HTMLElement. You forgot to get the text value _from_ that HTMLElement (e.g. by using `emails.textContent`, `emails.value`, etc). Also, don't use `alert`, it's a legacy function from an era we should not be trying to bring back. Use `console.log`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There's a good chance that the DOM element is an `input`, in which case `.textContent` won't apply. You'd need `.value` instead.

Comment: also an option, Bobby will know which to go with.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Not really. If it's an `input`, `textContent` won't work and it is most likely an `input`. If Bobby doesn't know what his simple errors are above, it's also a good bet he wouldn't know to use `.value` or `textContent`.

Comment: I think you commented right as I edited my comment to say "e.g. by using textContent" rather than saying textContent was the only option. I then added mention of .value, too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But it's still not correct. `.textContent` is NOT correct here. Also, you incorrectly state that `emails` is an HTML element, when it's actually `undefined`, and third `alert` is not a legacy function, it's a method of `window` and perfectly legitimate in 2020 to use.

Comment: No, it isn't. If it were `undefined`, the error would be `TypeError: can't access property "indexOf", emails is undefined`. And while Bobby's asking about a form, `textContent` is one of the two+manyother ways you can get string data from any HTML element and they'll benefit from hearing that. That's why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You cannot extract the value of an `input` with `.textContent`. I really don't know why you keep pushing that you can. An `input` has a closed content model, it cannot have any content. And since `emails` is not defined in the code shown, it will not be a reference to an HTML element. It will be `undefined`.

Comment: And I don't get why you keep thinking I'm saying you can get data from an input element using textContent, you can get text data from HTMLElements in a _lot_ of ways. textContent, value, getAttribute, dataset, etc. etc. This person should probably hear about all those.

Comment: *And I don't get why you keep thinking I'm saying you can get data from an input element using textContent* <-- Because every time you say this, you follow it (as you did above) with how you can use `.textContent`. No, in this case you can't so it should not be brought up in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your variable is `email`, but you are trying to call `indexOf` on `emails`.

Second, `email` is a reference to the element, not its value, and so `.indexOf()` won't work even after you call it with the right variable. Instead, you need to access the `.value` of the element, which is a string and something that you can call `indexOf` on.

```
function checker(){
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var name = document.getElementById('Name');
  var d = email.value.indexOf("@");  // call indexOf on the value of the element
  var x = email.value.indexOf(".");  // call indexOf on the value of the element

  if (d == -1)
    alert("Invalid email address given!!");
  else if (x == -1)
    alert("Invalid email address given!!");
  }
}
```

FYI: If you use `<input type="email">` in your HTML, you'll get email validation automatically and won't need this code in the first place.

Comment: Is this not a typo-type question not worth answering?

Comment: @mplungjan There is one typo, but even with it corrected, the second problem is not. As for the condition, you're right, but that wasn't what the question was asking about.

Comment: Typo-type - that includes not having a .value on trivial code imo

Comment: @mplungjan I disagree and would say that with that logic, just about any code mistake could be classified as a typo. If you are unaware of the difference between an element and its value, that's not a typo, it's a lack of understanding, not the accidental hitting of the wrong key.

Comment: It USED to be "localized error" as in "This problem is likely only yours" Now it is "_It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers_" which is the case when one reads and uses the information in the [1st comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589524/compiler-saying-indexof-function-isnt-a-function/60589569?noredirect=1#comment107192138_60589524) Just my opinion

Comment: PS: The "Use type=email" is a good one though, but as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `emails` is not defined so it does not have *any* methods on it. You are using `email` as the variable name.

As an aside, this is not an effective way to check for a valid email address, for example "....@@@" would pass but is obviously not a valid email address.

In my code I am using the following expression to check for valid email address client side, but this is still not 100% effective.

```
const pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

const email = 'email@example.com';

if (pattern.test(email)) {
   console.log('the email is valid');
} else {
   console.log('the email is not valid');
}
```

Comment: fixed that but its still saying the same thing

Comment: @BobbyMartins it's still possible for `email` to be undefined if there is no element with an ID of "email" in your document.